# Linear Regression (python) - error using multiple features

Tags: python, linear-regression

Pretty new to ML and python, so this may be a basic question, but hoping someone can give me a steer.

Have a weather dataset, and looking to develop a model for predicting temperature based off other features in the set (apparent temperature, humidity, visibility etc).

I have a model using 1 feature which seems to work well:

```
predictors1 = train[['apparent_temperature']]
response = train['temperature']

lr1 = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
lr1.fit(predictors1, response)
y_pred = lr1.predict(response)
```

when I go to make another model using more than 1 feature I get errors:

```
predictors2 = train[['apparent_temperature', 'humidity', 'visibility']]
response = train['temperature']

lr2 = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
lr2.fit(predictors2, response)
y_pred2 = lr2.predict(response)
```

error message I get is:

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 1)

Not sure if I'm reading this right, but this looks like a matrix multiplication issue - Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, or how to expand the model to take in more than 1 feature?

Comment: You are using the `predict` method incorrectly. The `predict` method takes the feature matrix `X` as input, not the response `y`. See the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict).